# Chart.js Tooltip Information

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

So I'm using Chart.js for results to a competition of sorts and in the tooltip, it only shows the number though I want to show a little more information right next to it.

For example, where it says "1234567", I want it to say "1234567 - 6 champs".

I was looking through the actual Chart.js file to add some code into but could find where I would add it. Because you add data like `data: [0, 10, 55, 1000, 444401]` and so on, I was thinking of adding a feature so you could add a string to each item in the array so something along the lines of the below:

```
data: [[0, "0 champs"],
    [10, "3 champs"],
    [55, "3 champs"],
    [1000, "4 champs"],
    [444401, "9 champs"]]
```

I don't care if it's like that exactly though is there a way I can add a string to go along with a value whether it's me adding code or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label within the chart options as detailed in the documentation, for example:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%> <%}%>(<%= value %> champs)"
```

Hope that helps! :)